# Input.ChoiceSet is reset when "Action.Execute" button is clicked in the card

Tags: microsoft-teams, adaptive-cards, microsoft-teams-js

I'm trying to implement the function that user can add tag in card using Input.ChoiceSet.
Since it seems there is no action invoked by selecting tag from the shown tag list(choises),
I'm trying to do it with "Action.Execute" button.
But when I click button, its added tag disappears from the input form.

How can I avoid it?

My current code is:

```
 public async onInvokeActivity(context: any): Promise<any> {
 if (
      context.activity.name === "adaptiveCard/action" &&
      context.activity.value.action.verb === "submitTags"
    ) {
      console.log(
        "adaptive card action is ",
        context.activity.value.action.data
      );
      const submittedTags = context.activity.value.action.data?.tagsChoiceSet;
      updateSelectedValuesInCard(submittedTags);

 return {
        status: 200,
        body: sentCard,
      };
    }

 ////other code

  return super.onInvokeActivity(context);
  }
```

```
function updateSelectedValuesInCard(newValues) {
  sentCard.attachments[0].content.body[5].value = newValues;

  sentCard.attachments[0].content.body[5].choices = newValues
    .split(",")
    .map((tag) => {
      return { title: tag, value: tag, selected: true };
    });

  console.log(
    "new values are ",
    newValues,
    "choices are ",
    sentCard.attachments[0].content.body[5].choices
  );
  return sentCard;
}
```

Card:

```
 sentCard = {
      type: "message",

      attachments: [
        {
          contentType: "application/vnd.microsoft.card.adaptive",
          contentUrl: null,
          content: {
            $schema: "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
            type: "AdaptiveCard",
            version: "1.4",
         
            body: [
            ///other code

              {
                type: "TextBlock",
                text: submittedMessage,
                wrap: true,
                size: "Medium",
              },
              {
                type: "TextBlock",
                weight: "Bolder",
                text: "Tags:",
                wrap: true,
                size: "Medium",
              },
              {
                type: "Input.ChoiceSet",
                id: "tagsChoiceSet",
                choices: tagsList,

                value: submittedTags,
                style: "filtered",
                "choices.data": {
                  type: "Data.Query",
                  dataset: "tagDataSet",
                },
                isMultiSelect: true,
              },
             
               ///other code

            ],
            actions: [
              {
                data: {
                  url: originalMessageURL,
                  id: "choosedTags",
                },

                type: "Action.Execute",
                title: "Save Tags",
                verb: "submitTags",
              },
            ],
          },
        },
      ],
    };
```

Comment: When the "Action.Execute" button is clicked in an Adaptive Card, it triggers an invoke request to your bot. By default, this invoke request will reset the values of the Input.ChoiceSet in the card. This behavior is intentional and designed to provide a consistent user experience.

If you want to preserve the selected values in the Input.ChoiceSet when the "Action.Execute" button is clicked, you can use the "data" property in the Action.Execute action. This property allows you to pass additional data along with the invoke request.